# PostgreSQL автоматическое обновление множества записей при обновлении одной

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица nodes(node_id, parent_id, is_deleted), как указать чтобы при обновлении is_deleted к true все записи где node_id = parent_id той записи которую обновляем получили также is_deleted - true или только запросом?

Comment: Запросом в триггере. только поаккуратнее с рекурсией. а то ведь при изменении этих записей их дочерние то же начнут апдейтится и если у вас вдруг где то связи окажутся цикличными будет плохо